# .Conversion error on unique identifier, shouldn't be referenced at all?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm working on the shopping cart for a website, I have this function that retrieves a voucher from my database:

```vb
Public Shared Function CheckForVoucher(ByVal strVoucherName As String) As DataTable
    Dim connect As New SqlConnection

    Dim Data As New DataTable    ''Connection works, finds number of Vouchers in DB that match either code or ID. ID to be used for randomly generated vouchers.

    connect.ConnectionString = "SERVER = SERVER-SQL01; Trusted_Connection=yes; DATABASE=PCSQL"
    connect.Open()

    Dim query As String
    Dim search As String
    search = strVoucherName
    If search.Length >= 25 Then
        query = "SELECT * from PCSQL.dbo.X_WW_VOUCHER_DETAILS WHERE vID='" & search & "' "
    Else
        query = "SELECT * from PCSQL.dbo.X_WW_VOUCHER_DETAILS WHERE voucherName='" & search & "' "
    End If

    Dim command = New SqlDataAdapter(query, connect)
    command.Fill(Data)
    connect.Close()
    strVoucherName = query
    Return Data
End Function
```

This all works peachy-keen on the site I'm working on. At the end of a customers order it fires another function, the increase the totalUses of the voucher by one (my boss wants to make sure that people don't spam the codes and run him out of business).

```
Public Shared Function addUse(ByVal strVoucherName As String, intCurrentUses As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim connect As New SqlConnection
    Dim data As New DataTable
    connect.ConnectionString = "SERVER = SERVER-SQL01; Trusted_Connection = yes; DATABASE=PCSQL"
    connect.Open()
    Dim query As String
    Dim name As String = strVoucherName
    Dim current As Integer = intCurrentUses
    Dim newint As Integer = current + 1
    query = "UPDATE dbo.X_WW_VOUCHER_DETAILS SET currentUses= @currentUses WHERE voucherName=@voucherName"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connect)
    command.Parameters.Add("@voucherName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters("@voucherName").Value = name
    command.Parameters.Add("@currentUses", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters("@currentUses").Value = newint

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connect.Close()
    Return True
End Function
```

This also works fine, and I can check the SQL table in SQL SERVER and see that the "currentUses" column has increased by one. Yay.

***Problem***

When I test the code by submitting again, it fails **if** the currentUses column is equal to the validUses column. I end up the error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier" even though the Unique Identifier is not directly referenced at all.

I've tested on a voucher that is valid 5 times. Times 1 through 4, no errors but as soon as currentUses was also 5... no go.

Why would equal columns cause my function to crap itself?

*SQL Table*

```
-vID    Uniqueidentifier
-voucherName    Nchar(15)
-expiryDate Date
-validUses  Int
-currentUses    Int
-discountType   Nchar(15)
-appliesTo  Nchar(15)
-numberOf   Nchar(20)
-Amount Int
-noOfItems  Int
-Category   Nchar(100)
-freebieID  Nchar(15)
-discountAmount Int
-Description    Nchar(255)
```

**EDIT**

I have narrowed the error down to this if statement.

```
If search.Length >= 25 Then
    query = "SELECT * from PCSQL.dbo.X_WW_VOUCHER_DETAILS WHERE vID='" & search & "' "
Else
    query = "SELECT * from PCSQL.dbo.X_WW_VOUCHER_DETAILS WHERE voucherName='" & search & "' "
End If
```

The Voucher itself is called from cart.aspx using

```
    Protected Sub btnVoucherCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVoucherCheck.Click

 Dim Data As DataTable = Voucher.CheckForVoucher(txtVoucher.text)
    If Data.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim row As DataRow
        row = Data.Rows(0)



        Voucher.VoucherID = row.Item("vID").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.VoucherName = row.Item("voucherName").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.ExpiryDate = row.Item("ExpiryDate")
        Voucher.ValidUses = row.Item("ValidUses")
        Voucher.CurrentUses = row.Item("CurrentUses")
        Voucher.DiscountType = row.Item("DiscountType").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.AppliesTo = row.Item("AppliesTo").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.NumberOf = row.Item("NumberOf").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.Amount = row.Item("Amount")
        Voucher.noOfItems = row.Item("NoOfItems")
        Voucher.Category = row.Item("Category").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.FreebieID = row.Item("FreebieID").ToString().Trim()
        Voucher.DiscountAmount = row.Item("DiscountAmount")


        Dim count As Int32
        count = 0

        Dim expiry As DateTime = Voucher.ExpiryDate
        Dim today As DateTime = Date.Today()
        count = ((expiry - today).Days)


        If count <= -1 Then
            txtVoucher.Text = "Voucher expired"
        Else                'Further checks. One: Valid uses against current uses, checks if too many people have used the voucher.
            If (Voucher.CurrentUses >= Voucher.ValidUses) Then
                txtVoucher.Text = "Sorry, Voucher is no longer valid"
            Else 'Redirects to one of three methods based on discount type.

                c.VoucherName = Voucher.VoucherName

                If c.discounted = True Then
                    For Each item As RepeaterItem In rptCart.Items
                        Dim quantity As TextBox = CType(item.FindControl("txtQuantity"), TextBox)
                        Dim ProductID As HyperLink = CType(item.FindControl("hlProductID"), HyperLink)
                        Dim lblPrice As Label = CType(item.FindControl("lblPrice"), Label)
                        lblPrice.Text = Product.GetProductPrice(ProductID.Text, quantity.Text, c)

                    Next
                End If

                Select Case Voucher.DiscountType
                    Case "Dollar"
                        txtVoucher.Text = "$ Not yet Supported"
                    Case "Percentage"
                        percentageDiscount()
                    Case "Freebie"
                        txtVoucher.Text = "Freebie Not Yet Supported"
                    Case Else
                        txtVoucher.Text = "Not working."
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Else


    End If
End Sub
```

The two relevant columns are compared in the middle of this function, but my code doesn't execute that far if they are equal to being with. I get the conversion error referencing the line in my CheckForVoucher function that I pasted above. It can't be my comparison that causes the error because the DataTable I use for that doesn't fully exist at the point the error occurs.

Comment: Impossible to tell from this limited information. Where does the error happen? What is the structure of your database?

Comment: Added a basic structure of the table, it's a standalone table only referenced by those two functions in my question. The error occurs when firing the first function while the currentUses and validUses are equal.

Comment: What is the value of `search.Length` when the first block gets executed?  You seem to think that's it's less than 25 but, unless something is corrupt, the fact that the code executes that way says otherwise.

Comment: That's what confuses me, the code is taken from a textbox.text. The string I've been passing is "test5off". When I remove the option, and force it to search by "vouchername" instead of "vID" it retrieves the "test5off" voucher correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is when the value of `search` is 25 characters or longer, you are passing it into the database to compare with the `vID` column. That column is a `uniqueidentifier` which means it's a GUID in C# terms. If the value you pass in cannot be converted directly to a GUID, then you will get a conversion error.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but the string being passed was "test5off" which should only have a length of 8 and not trigger a search for vID.

Comment: Then there is other code you have not shown here. How are the above functions called?

Comment: The function is called from the page cart.aspx using btnVoucherCheck_Click(). The code only calls the voucher, which is then used in other functions afterward. The button_click function fills a data table. "Dim Data as DataTable = Voucher.CheckForVoucher(txtVoucher.text)" with the txtVoucher variable being that 'test5off string.

Comment: It works correctly for vouchers that don't have equal values in 'currentUses' and 'validUses'... that's what weirds me out. It seems to be the change in the SQL table that breaks my function...

Comment: Please add that code to the question. Also, where do you check if the current uses equals the valid uses?

Comment: Question edited, the two columns aren't compared in vb until about 20 lines after the error occurs... weird?

Comment: You really need to add complete info or it's impossible to help. Please add more, the entire function!

Comment: More code added, but it checks other variables, the valid / current uses are only compared on one line, and not until after I get my error.

Comment: When it expires, it sets the text box to sat the voucher has expired, do you then use that message as the voucher name?

Comment: No, because it only runs that line if the DataTable has one or more rows in it, at which point I am no longer calling the CheckForVoucher() function, I am only referencing the DataTable result.

Comment: Every time you press the button you get a new DataTable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80611/discussion-between-chris-hinton-and-davidg).